# How to navigate to new page when dynamically generated table row is clicked

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a table which is dynamically generated, of which each row is clickable, Now the question is, I want a functionality that is when a row is clicked it should go to new page whose content would be dynamically generated based on which row is clicked

I am using servlets and jsp.

here is the jsp code where table is dynamically generated

```
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hostellist">
            <table>
            <tr >
            <th>Hostel Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Locality</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
            <%
            ArrayList<HostelInfoBean> list=(ArrayList<HostelInfoBean>)request.getAttribute("hostellist");
            Iterator<HostelInfoBean> listIterator = list.iterator();
            while(listIterator.hasNext()){
                HostelInfoBean bean = new HostelInfoBean();
                bean = listIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Hostelname in JSP : "+bean.getHostelName());
                %>
                <tr >
                <td><%=bean.getHostelName() %></td>
                <td><%=bean.getAddress() %></td>                    
                <td><%=bean.getLocality() %></td>
                <td><%= bean.getRating() %></td>
                <%boolean onclick=false;
                if(onclick){
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/linkinlist.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("hostelname", bean.getHostelName());
                rd.forward(request,response);}%>
                </tr>
                <% 
            }
            %>  

            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply generate a link to a new page and pass it the ID of the entity you want to edit, that's the way you can identify a resource via URL.

Comment: I relatively new at this,. it would be helpful if you can post an example

Comment: Instead of the `onclick` part to something like `<td><a href="/linkinlist.jsp?hostelname="<%=bean.getHostelName() %>"></a><%=bean.getHostelName() %></td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added an onclick event with specific servlet uri appending the hostelname as Smutje said.

here is the code

```
<tr onclick="window.document.location='DemoController?hostelName=<%=bean.getHostelName()%>'">
                <td><%=bean.getHostelName() %></td>
                <td><%=bean.getAddress() %></td>                    
                <td><%=bean.getLocality() %></td>
                <td><%= bean.getRating() %></td>
                </tr>
                <%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the data in the rows as url you can do this by url rewriting and by clicking on that particular data make the control go to that related servlet where you can get that particular data from web page by request or session object based on your requirement and based on the data you get you can navigate to the next page by writing business logic of what has to be displayed next